# Putty around a new kitchen sink drain

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, drain, putty

This may sound too simple, but I know nothing about it. My kitchen sink drain was replaced and a small amount of putty comes off around the diameter. I know that is normal but am I suppose to let that 'cure' with no water contact for a certain amount of time? I'm afraid the water (especially HOT) will cause it to remain soft and will keep it having to be wiped off, eventually removing too much of it! I forgot to ask the man that put the drain in and can't reach him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The putty is plumbers putty which doesn't need to cure, and in fact shouldn't ever shrink, crack, or harden. It's safe to use your sink immediately and just remove any excess that squeezes out. The only concern is if it continues to squeeze out more after you remove the excess, that may be a sign that the drain wasn't tightened down enough.